# In which directory are the files for Python mode in Processing 3.0.1 are living?

Tags: python, processing, jython-2.7

I'm using Processing 3.0.1 on Windows 10. I have installed Python mode.
As I understand Python mode in Processing 3.0.1 uses Jython 2.7.x.
Can some one tell me in which directory I can find the Python/Jython stuff?

Kind regards

Klaus

Answer (score -1):

Look in the **Processing sketchbook directory**. You can find the location of this directory by going to **File** -> **Preferences**, and looking at the sketchbook location setting at the top.

In your sketchbook directory, you should see a `modes` directory, and in that you'll find a `PythonMode` directory. The `jython.jar` file is in the `mode` directory.

For example, my `jython.jar` file is located at `C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Processing3\modes\PythonMode\mode\jython.jar`.

You could also just search your computer for `jython`.